# How to make 'file_get_contents' accessing a remote URL use the original hyperlinks?

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I'm trying to insert a .php file into the body of a webpage using 'file_get_contents'. When the remote content is displayed, non of the links work because it requests them locally. As a  bit of a newbie, is there a way to set the 'file_get_contents' output to display the original hyperlinks? Would a context variable be the solution?

This is my php in the webpage:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://acs.klikapps.co.uk/stock.php"); ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: file_get_contents() won't do this for you.... you'd need to get the result of the file_get_contents() in a variable, and then parse that to identify and modify the links using [domDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php echo str_replace("stock.php?", "http://acs.klikapps.co.uk/stock.php?", file_get_contents("http://acs.klikapps.co.uk/stock.php")); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to either modify the returned HTML to replace the relative links with an absolute path, or an easier solution could be to add a `<base href='http://the-site.com/folder/" />` tag to the `<head>` of the returned page.